# String.to_datetime does not use the current timezone (when none given)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I noticed that Rails' [String.to_timezone](http://apidock.com/rails/String/to_datetime) method does not use the current time zone, when no time zone is given in the string.

```
$ "2013-01-14 14:38".to_datetime
=> Mon, 14 Jan 2013 14:38:00 +0000
$ DateTime.now
=> Mon, 14 Jan 2013 14:39:50 +0100
```

Is there a way to tell the method to use the current time zone?

Thanks.

Comment: `Time.zone.parse("2013-01-14 14:38")` ?

Comment: That's better, but it doesn't solve my requirement "when no time zone is given".

Comment: It uses timezone set in `config/application.rb`.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. If I supply `"2013-01-14 14:38"`, then it should be parsed using the current time zone. If I supply `2013-01-14 14:38 +0100`, then it should take the supplied time zone (`+0100`).

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
Time.zone.parse('2013-01-14 14:38').to_datetime
```

This will use the current timezone to parse the string to date.

Comment: Yes, This works! If you test in `rails console`, at first set the `timezone` in console: `Time.zone = "Dhaka"`

Answer (score 6):

There's [#in_time_zone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-in_time_zone) method on the `DateTime` object you can use:

```
"2013-01-14 14:38".to_datetime.in_time_zone
"2013-01-14 14:38".to_datetime.in_time_zone("Prague")
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. `"2013-01-14 16:06".to_datetime.in_time_zone` results in `Mon, 14 Jan 2013 17:06:00 CET +01:00`, expected result: Mon, 14 Jan 2013 16:06:00 CET +01:00` (16:06 o'clock, not 17:06 o'clock).

Comment: Note that the time you are converting from is not the zone being provided - it's a conversion from the default timezone to the timezone being provided. In this case it's from UTC.

Answer (score 4):

Use `in_time_zone`:

```
"2013-01-14 16:06".in_time_zone
=> Mon, 14 Jan 2013 16:06:00 CET +01:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"2013-01-14 16:06".in_time_zone
```

Or

```
"2013-01-14 16:06".in_time_zone
```

No other answers.